# Is this a good sql schema to power an in-site search box?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a site which is a database of Japanese drama shows, for an English-speaking audience. Amusingly, this particular case means that each page has multiple (about four, but sometimes more) search terms that a user could try to use to find the show.

This is the MySQL schema I have come up with to power an in-site search box which will have typeahead functionality.

```
CREATE TABLE `search` (
    `showid` INT(15) NOT NULL ,
    `displayname` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
    `altnames` VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I plan to use this by putting the lowercase version of the name in english, hepburn, romanji and kanji into the 'altnames' column, each seperated by a newline character. Then, to perform a search I will first make the search term all lowercase with PHP, then use a query like...

```
SELECT showid, displayname FROM search WHERE altnames LIKE "%search term%\n"
```

Is this schema the best available? Is it scalable (with a Redis cache in front of it)? Which collation should I use in order to store both latin and Japanese characters alongside each other?

Comment: That's more than one question. For collating, you should *always* use utf-8.

Comment: I mostly just want to know if this is a good and scalable schema, or if someone has a better idea. I figured I'd double-check about the collation while I was at it, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would split the schema into two tables. This may add some overhead but will make it more scalable and more intuitive (at least I would find it more intuitive).

I would keep your first table but remove the altnames column. If this ever becomes something large with dozens of alt names your search could become very slow.

```
CREATE TABLE `search` (
    `showid` INT(15) NOT NULL ,
    `displayname` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I would then replace that altnames column with an altnames table that has a many-to-one relationship with the search table:

```
CREATE TABLE `search_altnames` (
    `id` INT(15) NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT , 
    `displayname_id` INT(15) NOT NULL ,
    `altname` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`displayname_id`) REFERENCES search(`showid`)
)
```

To search you would do something like the following:

```
SELECT s.`showid`, s.`displayname`
FROM `search_altnames` sa
INNER JOIN `search` s ON s.`showid` = sa.`displayname_id`
WHERE sa.`altname` LIKE 'search term'
```

Like I said, I think that would be more scalable. Hope that helps and good luck!

**EDIT**
[Here](http://www.ovaistariq.net/479/mysql-query-optimization-tip-1-avoid-using-wildcard-character-at-the-start-of-a-like-pattern/) is a link to a page why wildcard searches are slow.

Comment: I could actually do this without the join, as my Redis cache usually already contains the show data for each id. So having a separate row for each search term would be faster than pushing them all together into one column?

Comment: Doing a like search with the wildcard operators (%) on each side is slow for large fields. With your four languages it would probably be okay but if you ever need to expand your altnames to where there is something like 10 or more of them per displayname then there will likely be a noticable speed difference. Whereas searching through more rows in a separate table shouldn't affect it nearly as much.

Comment: I just edited my answer adding a link that explains why wildcard searches are slow.